# Is there method to convert @Composable into .pdf with all offscreen content?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

I have composable fun with a lot of content, which scrolls. I need method to convert firstly it to bitmap and then to pdf.

I try to convert it into bitmap using this library

```
implementation ("dev.shreyaspatil:capturable:1.0.3")
```

And then convert into pdf

```
fun createPdf(bitmap: Bitmap, outputPath: String, context: Context) {
    val pdfWriter = PdfWriter(outputPath)
    val pdfDoc = PdfDocument(pdfWriter)
    val document = Document(pdfDoc)

    val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
    val imageData = ImageDataFactory.create(stream.toByteArray())
    val image = Image(imageData)

    document.add(image)
    document.close()
    shareFile(context, outputPath)
}
```

it's work, but it returns for me only screen content, like screenshot but i need also off screen content .
How to do that ?

Comment: Did you find the solution @Yarik Nikolenko?